# starting chrome without asking to save password window

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

While running tests using Selenium and Java, every time I log into a site I get this annoying popup window "Do you want Chrome to save your password?".  This table blocks what Selenium is looking for so my element underneath will not be found, and the test fails.

I read you could go to advanced settings and uncheck the box, which I did.  However, it still shows that window popup.  I am guessing it is because we start up a new Chrome each time and so Chrome does not remember previous options.  Chrome is being started via Selenium and Java.

Is there some way that Chrome can be started up without the password window?  A flag or something, perhaps?

I am using Chrome 57.  Someone got Chrome 55 and has me use it but Chrome updates automatically so it reset back to 57.  I don't think that matters anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start Chrome disabling Password Manager you need to:

1. Download and use the latest chrome driver from [this link](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/).
2. Add the preferences & options to your code as follows:

   ```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\SeleniumUtilities\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
   Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);
   prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
   prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
   ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
   capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
   WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
   driver.get("http:\\gmail.com");
   ```

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: thanks.  IO can't see how prefs makes it into the crhome command?

Comment: @Tony Check my updated code and let me know if that works for you. Thanks

Comment: Trying it now.  Not sure they will let me add all those options.  I will see.  Thanks

Comment: @Tony Reduced some more code for your convenience. Check & let me know the status.

Comment: Yes, thanks.  They put me back to Chrome 55 but I was able to test with your above code.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Tony I am glad that I was able to help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add following preferences:

```
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
prefs.put("password_manager_enabled", false); 
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
```

Comment: You won't be able to use the "options" object untill & unless you create it first.